# Rewrite Rule Not working .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL which I am trying to make SEO friendly URL. I tried a few of the online rewrite validators and they validated perfect for the rules which I have written in .htaccess, but it's still not working when uploaded to my server. Any help is really appreciated.

I want `http://example.com/deal/de3582c47f/` to be redirected (without actually changing the URL for the end user) to `http://example.com/dealinfo.php?offerid=de3582c47f`.

There are multiple sites deployed in the common root directory. 
Below are my .htaccess rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^deal/(.+)/$ dealinfo.php?offerid=$1 [L]
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your question is missing what behaviour you observe right now. Is mod_rewrite installed and did you restart the service after doing that? Have you tested if your .htaccess file is actually read? Write garbage in it and look if a 500 internal server error is shown. Do you have permission to override fileinfo in your .htaccess file? This has to be set in httpd.conf, and after changes to that file Apache needs to be restarted as well.

Comment: For future reference. "Redirecting" refers to sending a redirect header (301 permanent, or 302 temporary) and changing the url in the address bar. What you want to do is called "Internal rewrite"

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  Currently the page is displaying a 404 page not found.  I tried to create the page to display loaded modules as I am using php. phpiinfo didn't find the string "mod_rewrite". Is there a way I can still achieve this internal redirection without .htaccess assuming that "mod_rewrite" is not there

Answer (score 1):

actually.. the RewriteCond rules you have, only tell the latest rule, that they should work on those domains.

does the virtualhost definition has AllowOverride all?

but i would go with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^deal/(.+)/ /dealinfo.php?offerid=$1 [L]
```

i added a slash at the begining of dealinfo.php, so it will look on documentRoot folder defined on the virtualhost for your domain, instead of the actual 'fake' folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the problem is with the installation of mod rewrite on fat cow.com. I have checked with host gator and they do provide the access and required modules preinstalled even if it's a shared environment. Hope it works.

Comment: @user3580094 Curious, fatcow do advertise that their hosting works with WordPress and Joomla. URL rewriting (using mod_rewrite as you have above) is an important part of these CMSs. Although perhaps not absolutely essential, it would be wrong to advertise it as compatible if this was not possible!?

Comment: W3d, I agree that they should not advertise. Either I am doing something really wrong or they giving wrong information to me. I have verified what Erwin has suggested and still not working. Since this is shared environment, I don't I have or anyone who is in shaded environment has the rights to restart apache or modfiy httpd.conf. I am more than willing to follow any more instructions so that I can verify this further and confirm if they are fooling us around

Comment: check if in your panel, you have access to your vhosts error logs, so you can check what's wrong. i'll check what you're trying to do on a vps i mounted at home.

Comment: i've realized that if you don't put RewriteEngine on at the begining, it wont work. to check if rewrite is enabled on your hosting, you can put a php file, with $isenabled = in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())  then check if $isenabled is true or false.

Comment: @Erwin, Thanks for providing further inputs. I have moved entire rewrite rules section to the very beginning of the .htaccess file and (file now starts with "RewriteEngine on") tested again, resulted in same error as before - 404 error page not found. For the apache_get_modules(), seems fatcow doesn't allow or the function itself is blocked for execution --> Log Content "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()".